Objective-C char array initialization causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing property
I was getting an error EXC_BAD_ACCESS for seemingly no reason. After a lot of debugging I found the problem but I have no idea why it occurs.
Here's some examples of when it happens:

MyObject.h

@interface MyFile : NSObject

@property (strong) NSFileHandle *handle;

@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    int bufferSize;
    NSMutableArray *files;
}

- (void)readFile1;
- (void)readFile2;
- (void)readFile3;
- (void)readFile4;

@end


MyObject.m

@implementation MyObject

- (id)init
{
    bufferSize = 200000000;
    // Initialize files array, add a file object and open the file handle.
}

- (void)readFile1
{
    UInt64 bytesToProcess;
    file = [files objectAtIndex:0];
    char *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
    
    do @autoreleasepool {
        NSFileHandle *handle = [file handle];
        bytesToProcess = [data = [handle readDataOfLength:bufferSize] length];
        [data getBytes:buffer length:bytesToProcess]; // This works fine.
        // Modify the buffer.
    } while (bytesToProcess);
}

- (void)readFile2
{
    UInt64 bytesToProcess;
    file = [files objectAtIndex:0];
    char buffer[bufferSize];
    
    do @autoreleasepool {
        NSFileHandle *handle = [file handle]; // This throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
        bytesToProcess = [data = [handle readDataOfLength:bufferSize] length];
        [data getBytes:buffer length:bytesToProcess];
        // Modify the buffer.
    } while (bytesToProcess);
}

- (void)readFile3
{
    UInt64 bytesToProcess;
    file = [files objectAtIndex:0];
    char buffer[10];
    
    do @autoreleasepool {
        NSFileHandle *handle = [file handle];
        bytesToProcess = [data = [handle readDataOfLength:10] length];
        [data getBytes:buffer length:bytesToProcess]; // This works fine.
        // Modify the buffer.
    } while (bytesToProcess);
}

- (void)readFile4
{
    UInt64 bytesToProcess;
    file = [files objectAtIndex:0];
    
    do @autoreleasepool {
        NSFileHandle *handle = [file handle];
        bytesToProcess = [data = [handle readDataOfLength:bufferSize] length];
        char buffer[bufferSize];
        [data getBytes:buffer length:bytesToProcess]; // This throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
        // Modify the buffer.
    } while (bytesToProcess);
}

@end

I don't understand why this became a problem out of nowhere, the code was working for a long time and consistently stopped working all of a sudden. I assume malloc allocates the memory a bit differently. I don't understand how initializing an array makes my object inaccessible, I don't expect it to overwrite allocated memory.
What is the difference between char buffer[10]; and char *buffer = malloc(10);? I thought it was the same thing.

Your code doesn't compile, post real code please (probably [data getBytes:buffer length:10]). Does NSFileHandle *handle = […] crash? I don't see a property in your code.

@Willeke Thanks for letting me know, I did indeed mix that up while simplifying the code. I updated the provided code, now it's more like the original code but I still removed parts because there is a lot of it that isn't related to the problem. If you can't replicate the issue and want the full original code I can provide you it all.

It was the char buffer[10] crash in the original examples that threw us all off. Pushing 10 bytes on to the stack would invariably not be a problem. But 200mb would easily cause a problem. And malloc, accessing memory from the heap, avoids stack memory limitations. Thanks for clarifying the question. So, did Chris answer your question?

A few orders of magnitude to consider what you should allocate on the stack vs heap: IIRC, the stack size is 1mb in iOS, and defaults to 8mb in macOS (though it can be overridden by linker options). Generally, I would shy away from stack allocations in excess of a kb or two except in the most extraordinary cases.

Why one isn't working in your situation requires more details to answer definitively.

What is the difference between char buffer[10]; and char *buffer = malloc(10);? I thought it was the same thing.

This question is more answerable.
In the former case, ten bytes are automatically allocated on the stack if located within a function. Attempting to return a pointer to that memory outside of the function will result in undefined behavior as that memory may be reused by another function call on the stack and therefore is no longer valid outside the function call.
In the latter case using malloc, the memory is dynamically allocated. A pointer to it can be returned from a function and used in another function. However, the memory is not automatically reclaimed and must be deliberately freed with free.
Depending on how you're using this memory, this may very well explain why using malloc works and char buffer[10]; doesn't. I strongly suggest compiling with warnings on.
Stack space
With your edited code, where bufferSize is 200000000 we can now see that in readFile2 and readFile4 you're trying to put two hundred million bytes on the stack. This is a situation where you really would need dynamic allocation.
Even with dynamic memory allocation, you're trying to allocate two hundred million bytes in one block. That's a lot of memory. You may want to rethink your approach to see if you can work in smaller chunks.

Does the data on the stack need to be of a constant size or can the size be determined using a variable that can change depending on the previous code? Thanks for explaining the difference, it makes more sense now. I am experienced with managed languages so I'm not used to manual memory management. If I try to use free(buffer)I get an error "Expected expression" and the description of the free function is "free(void *) Frees all of the resources allocated by the IOAudioPort". Could it be that I have to use an alternative to free in Objective-C?

You can only free that which has been allocated using malloc, realloc, or calloc.

In C you can have variable length arrays on the stack, where the length is determined by a variable. Keep in mind, though, that stack space is limited, so ensure that variable is relatively small.

thanks for the information, it's probably indeed be the size that's causing problems on the stack. I don't think free exists in Objective-C for SDK versions for Mac OS older than 10.13 High Sierra. I can't find any information on how to use free in Objective-C for an SDK older than that. There has to be another way to free the memory, if I run my application in instruments I see a lot of memory kept by malloc that doesn't appear to be freed after the function finishes and only goes away when the application restarts. ARC doesn't see the malloc stuff and I can't use standard C functions.

I recompiled the code and now free suddenly works like it should, I looked in Instruments and it makes a clear difference, the memory immediately drops to almost 0 when I free everything up as soon as it's not necessary anymore. I don't know why Xcode describes it as being a thing for IOAudioPort since it works for everything. Apple's documentation says 10.13 and higher but it works fine for me and I wouldn't know why some C functions aren't available in Objective-C. I'm finally starting to understand the stack and heap a bit more. Thanks a lot for the help!
